# How to make one page website with background color change on div change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a one page website which is having left menu fixed and its contents on right side..

I want body background color different for different menus.. it should also work for scroll up and scroll down also...

And also as menu changes that menu should be highlighted...

http://mailchimp.com/2012/#!/section/
Please check this url. I want to make something same as in this site..

Is there any plugin to make this type of site???

Please reply as early as possible..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Going through their source Mailchimp did it themselves with jQuery + CSS transitions.

Comment: @BasaratAli: sorry i didnt got..??

Answer (score 2):

You should listen for a click event on your menu items, and change the background-color for your body. You can store the color for each div in a `data` property:

```
$('.menu_item').on('click', function(){
    var newColor = $(this).data('color');
    $('body').css('background-color', newColor);
});
```

Comment: yes, your should listen for the scroll event for that : `$(document).on('scroll', function(){ ... });`

Comment: @gabitzish nice and elegant solution +1